# How to create two different types of Overdue rent turn

Tags: java

My two different local dates of overdue is not printing. The only one that prints is the upper one, and where I can put the availability again for renting?

```
    public void displayOverdue() {
        List<Rent> rents = new ArrayList<Rent>();
        LocalDate rentDate = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.MARCH, 15);
        LocalDate dueDate = rentDate.plusDays(30);
        if (dueDate.isBefore(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Malta")))) {
            System.out.println("The rented bike is Overdue; was due on " + dueDate);


        LocalDate rentDate1 = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.APRIL, 15);
        LocalDate dueDate1 = rentDate1.plusDays(30);
         if (dueDate1.isBefore(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Malta")))) {
             System.out.println("The rented bike is Overdue; was due on " + dueDate1);  
            }
        }

        }
```

Addedd  my Rent class

```
import java.util.*;
import java.time.*;

public class Rent implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private int days;
    protected LocalDate dateOfRent;
    protected LocalDate returnDate;
    boolean availability= true;
List<Rent> rents = new ArrayList<Rent>();
    //getter---setter methods





    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Bike name:" + name + " Days: " + days;
    }
```

Comment: What does the `Rent` class look like?

Comment: If you run your program on or after May 15, both dates will be printed out.